# Confused with typedef usage

Tags: c++, c

I encountered code where:

```
typedef wchar_t     str_param_t[WP_STR_MAX_LEN];
```

And then:

```
typedef struct work_t
{
    u32_t           val1;
    u32_t           val2;
    str_param_t     data[WP_MAX_COUNT_STR];
} work_t;
```

My question is what type is `data`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an array of length `WP_MAX_COUNT_STR` containing `wchar_t`-based strings of length `WP_STR_MAX_LEN` each.

Comment: So is it a one dimensional array? I see it's usage further in code like `if (_items_s->data[no][WP_STR_MAX_LEN-1]) rc = s_string(_items_s->data[no], WP_STR_MAX_LEN);` and it further confused me, especially `if` part

Comment: @dmcr_code: It can be treated as a one-dimensional array of strings, or as a two-dimensional array of `wchar_t`s. In your example, `_items_s->data[no][WP_STR_MAX_LEN-1]` is a single `wchar_t`, and `_items_s->data[no]` is the whole string (well, the function receives a pointer to it).

Comment: It's an array of strings. Each string can also be seen as an array, so in that sense it's a 2D array.

Comment: @Gassa: So basically it's like `data[0]` can be 1 string right? from `data[12]` another string can start, and finally from `data[24]` also another string can start? In case `WP_STR_MAX_LEN=12`. So we just have three strings of fixed length.

Comment: @dmcr_code: Not quite so. Say `WP_STR_MAX_LEN` is 5 and `WP_MAX_COUNT_STR` is 8. Then the 0-th string consists of five characters: `data[0][0]`, `data[0][1]`, ..., `data[0][4]`. The 1-st string consists of five other characters which can be accessed as `data[1][0]`, `data[1][1]`, ..., `data[1][4]`. And so on, the last (7-th if there are 8 of them) string consists of `data[7][0]`, `data[7][1]`, ..., `data[7][4]`. A visual analogy is a rectangle of 8 rows and 5 columns containing letters, strings being the rows of the rectangle.

Comment: @Gassa: I understand `data` basically contains a certain number (`WP_MAX_COUNT_STR`) of fixed length (`WP_STR_MAX_LEN`) strings right?
What did you mean with "_items_s->data[no] is the whole string"? - I think `data[no]`-is the `no`-th string?

Comment: @dmcr_code: yes, it is the whole `no`-th string, and the context is that `_items_s->data[no][WP_STR_MAX_LEN-1]` is a single character of that one whole string.

Comment: @Gassa: Ok, understand not sure why there was a check for a single character though inside if. So basically it is a two dimensional array  (`no` - is row number basically in the rectangle you mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

the type of `data` is 2D array of type wchar_t.

```
typedef wchar_t     str_param_t[WP_STR_MAX_LEN];
str_param_t     data[WP_MAX_COUNT_STR];
```

this is equal to:

```
wchar_t data[WP_STR_MAX_LEN][WP_MAX_COUNT_STR];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain you in simple about `typedef`

Like

```
typedef string FiveStrings[5];
```

By defining `typedef string FiveStrings[5]`, `FiveStrings` can be used to declare an array of 5 strings with each string being of type string(`char *`).

Now you can use above new type name as follows

```
FiveStrings countries = { "Ghana", "Angola", "Togo",

                          "Tunisia", "Cote d'Ivoire" };
```